# I thought it was the other way around vs I would've thought it was the other way around

Tags: meaning

> "I'm the chick and Chandler's the duck."
>   "I would've thought it was the other way around."

These sentences are from the television show *Friends*.

I think instead of the second sentence, using *I thought it was the other way around* is not wrong.

I don't know exactly what is different between that two sentences in terms of meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The *would've* changes the subtext of the sentence.

> I thought it was the other way around. — simple statement, perhaps a little confrontational or contrary
>
> I would've thought it was the other way around. — acknowledgement of a different understanding and acceptance of new information

Comment: In other words, "I would have thought it was the other way round [if you had not just told me that]."